# How can I publish an MVC 4 application on visual studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

When I try to publish it I get the following error message:

Error 1 Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("***.***.*.***"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

I dont understand why is it referring me to a remote computer, I've specified the destination URL as my own IP address. And I have web management service checked on windows features.

How do I solve this particular error?

Comment: look at this link and see if it helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178109(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to publish to the file system, if this works move the files into you wwwroot, normally c:\inetpub\www.

then go to start and run inetmgr to open iis configuration manager, if you see your folder there right click and convert to application, accept settings then right click / manage / browse and you should see your site or an IIS error that should be easy to debug.

I never use the deploy to IIS feature from VS as it's pants.

Good luck!